# Calling Tableau using REST Assured returning a 403

Tags: java, api, automated-tests, tableau-api, rest-assured

Currently writing an automation test to log a user in that has Tableau credentials and call a Tableau endpoint. However, each time I do this, I receive a 403 with a NOT_AUTHORISED message. I've done the exact same call on Postman using the same credentials and I get a 200 on there fine. I ran through this issue with one of our devs and we tried experiment with different ways of calling the same endpoint using REST assured (changing cookies and headers etc), but it's either a 403 or a 401.

The function that calls the endpoint is below:

```
return given().cookie(cookie).contentType(ContentType.JSON).get("tableau/projects");
```

The cookie value is a string that contains the access_token, refresh_token, and the tableau_token, and is formatted like below:

```
"access_token=BLAHBLAHBLAH; refresh_token=BLAHBLAHBLAH; tableau_token=BLAHBLAHBLAH"
```

I am completely stuck with this one.

Answer (score 1):

Most of the cases I've encountered is using "Bearer token", you just put `access_token` to header to Authentication (solve 401 error).

```
.header("Authorization", "Bearer BLAHBLAHBLAH")
```

But for 403 error, it means you're authenticated, but not allowed to access this resource, you could use the account that has privileges.

Comment: The account does have privileges. I've tested it manually on Postman and it is allowed to access the resource when manually making the call on Postman.

Comment: If it works on postman then it should work on RA, could you provide setting on postman? or Tableau api documentation that defines the request to see what else you've missed.